# Does Dell's iDRAC come with its own Ethernet Port?

Tags: dell, keyboard-video-mouse

Does Dell's iDRAC come with its own Ethernet Port, or will I have to dedicate one of my regular Ethernet ports (Broadcom onboard) for the DRAC IPKVM traffic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dell provide an integrated BMC(IPMI) and basic iDRAC services on virtually all current generation servers as standard - they call this iDRAC6 Express. It does not support out of band Console access (apart from Serial over LAN which is a fairly limited text mode console) and uses one of the onboard Broadcom LOM's. The only current generation Dell servers where the iDRAC6 Express is not a standard feature that I'm aware of are the T110 and the C-Series range of high density systems.

iDRAC6 Enterprise is an extra cost on most systems where it is supported and that adds a dedicated management port, full remote console that supports GUI interfaces, and some other features. The only systems that come with this as standard are the M Series Blade servers.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I ordered the iDRAC6 Enterprise. Expensive... $349. But I'm glad it comes with a dedicated port.

Answer (score 3):

It has it's own ethernet port.

Comment: There are two types of DRAC's integrated, and dedicated. One has its own port, the other piggybacks on one of the on-board NICs. Be sure to specify this when you order your server.